# Installing SymEngine in julia on macOSX

Tags: julia, sympy

I compiled **julia** from the sources on macOS Mojave Version 100.14.6,
I can add and build various other packages. I added the **SymEngine** 
using the the command:

```
 using Pkg
 Pkg.add("SymEngine")
```

However when I try to build the package using:

```
Pkg.build("SymEngine")
```

I got the following error:

```
  Building SymEngine → `~/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/build.log`
  Updating `/private/var/folders/n0/wcd6_xw90f524sc0sxkcw81r0000gn/T/jl_V899mt/Project.toml`
 [no changes]
  Updating `/private/var/folders/n0/wcd6_xw90f524sc0sxkcw81r0000gn/T/jl_V899mt/Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]
┌ Error: Error building `SymEngine`:
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpfr.6.dylib
│ [ Info: nothing
│ [ Info: nothing
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.10.dylib while looking for libgmp
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libgmp.10.dylib matches our search criteria of libgmp
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.10.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmpxx.4.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmpxx.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpc.3.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpc.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpfr.6.dylib while looking for libmpfr
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpfr.6.dylib matches our search criteria of libmpfr
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.10.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmpxx.4.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmpxx.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpc.3.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.3.dylib matches our search criteria of libmpc
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.3.dylib cannot be dlopen'ed
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpc.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.dylib matches our search criteria of libmpc
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.dylib cannot be dlopen'ed
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpfr.6.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpfr.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libsymengine.0.4.0.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libsymengine.0.4.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libsymengine.dylib while looking for libmpc
│ [ Info: Could not locate libmpc inside /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.10.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmp.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmpxx.4.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libgmpxx.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpc.3.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpc.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpfr.6.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libmpfr.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libsymengine.0.4.0.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libsymengine.0.4.0.dylib matches our search criteria of libsymengine
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libsymengine.0.4.0.dylib cannot be dlopen'ed
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libsymengine.0.4.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libsymengine.0.4.dylib matches our search criteria of libsymengine
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libsymengine.0.4.dylib cannot be dlopen'ed
│ [ Info: Found a valid dl path libsymengine.dylib while looking for libsymengine
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libsymengine.dylib matches our search criteria of libsymengine
│ [ Info: /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libsymengine.dylib cannot be dlopen'ed
│ [ Info: Could not locate libsymengine inside /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib
│ ERROR: LoadError: LibraryProduct("/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib", ["libmpc"], :libmpc, nothing) is not satisfied, cannot generate deps.jl!
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] write_deps_file(::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}; verbose::Bool) at /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/kcGxO/src/Products.jl:414
│  [3] write_deps_file(::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/kcGxO/src/Products.jl:395
│  [4] top-level scope at /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/build.jl:60
│  [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:439
│  [6] top-level scope at none:5
│ in expression starting at /Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/build.jl:60
└ @ Pkg.Operations ~/Work/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:883
```

But **libmpc** is installed:

```
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/mpc-1.1.0/lib/libmpc.3.dylib
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/mpc-1.1.0/lib/libmpc.dylib
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/mpc-1.1.0/lib/libmpc.la
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/mpc-1.1.0/logs/fix_identity_mismatch_libmpc.3.dylib.log
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/mpc-1.1.0/logs/update_linkage_libmpc.3.dylib_libgmp.10.dylib.log
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/mpc-1.1.0/logs/update_linkage_libmpc.3.dylib_libmpfr.6.dylib.log
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/symengine-0.4.0/logs/update_linkage_libsymengine.0.4.0.dylib_libmpc.3.dylib.log
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/downloads/symengine-0.4.0/logs/update_rpath_libmpc.3.dylib.log
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.3.dylib
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.dylib
/Users/ruben/.julia/packages/SymEngine/zSUGO/deps/libsymengine-0.4/lib/libmpc.la
```

Any one managed to overcome this issue with SymEngine on macOS?